# How to increment a letter per group

Tags: sql-server, character, auto-increment

I have a list of containers (over 2K rows) that I want to split into number of comparments

```
Code Name    Compartments
10   10 feet   1 
15   15 feet   1
25   25 feet   2
100  100 feet  3
150  150 feet  2
```

I did this query to achieve that

```
select * 
from Containers c
inner join master.dbo.spt_values b on b.type = 'P' and b.number < c.Compartments
```

To get

```
Code Name    Compartments
10   10 feet   1 
15   15 feet   1
25   25 feet   2
25   25 feet   2
100  100 feet  3
100  100 feet  3
100  100 feet  3
150  150 feet  2
150  150 feet  2
```

Now I want to add an auto-increment letter on the code, but per group like this.

```
Code Name    Compartments
10A   10 feet   1 
15A   15 feet   1
25A   25 feet   2
25B   25 feet   2
100A  100 feet  3
100B  100 feet  3
100C  100 feet  3
150A  150 feet  2
150B  150 feet  2
```

I was thinking to use the number of compartments or adding an identity column to add anm incremental char(64), but I can't figure out how to make the incremental per group

```
select Code + CHAR(Compartments + 64), *  
from Containers c inner join master.dbo.spt_values b on b.type = 'P' and
b.number < c.Compartments
```

Comment: Have you considered using `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Have you considered not doing this? Honestly an "incrementing" letter it fraught with issues. What happens when you get to 27? Do you now have AA? How are you going to sort those when AA should come after Z? How about the whole slew of combinations you really don't want. Like what comes after FUJ? Or after SEW? How many other 2-3 letter combinations can you make that should be excluded??? And cramming the existing plus another value into the same tuple violates 1NF, that should be two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for you but remember to check after 26 meaning what will happen when you reach 'Z'.

```
select Code + CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY name ASC) + 64), *  
from Containers c inner join master.dbo.spt_values b on b.type = 'P' and
b.number < c.Compartments
```

Comment: That will work, but as Sean pointed out, this is a **really** bad design.